# How to send json serialize data from a form to ajax using django

Tags: ajax, django

Currently, I'm sending the data via code in this way and it's working but how can I send the entire form in json?

Code :

```
 $.ajax({
         url : window.location.href, // the endpoint,commonly same url
         type : "POST", // http method
         data : { csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrftoken,
         email : email,
         password : password,
         username : username,
         dob : dob,
 }, // data sent with the post request
```

I want to send and retrieve everything including **csrfmiddlewaretoken** using formdata json.

I have tried something similar to that :

```
    var formData = new FormData($('#my_form');
    formData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');

 $.ajax({
         url : window.location.href, // the endpoint,commonly same url
         type : "POST", // http method
         data : formData, // data sent with the post request
```

But, this does not work for some reason. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to send json serialized form data as one paramater and csrf token as another parameter because every POST request expects a csrf token in it.

```
    csrfmiddlewaretoken = $("#add_member_Form").find("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']" ).val();
    formData = $('#add_member_Form').serializeArray();
    formData = JSON.stringify(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : {
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : csrfmiddlewaretoken,
            "formData" : formData
        },
        method: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
```

At server side in your view, you need to deserialize the data.

```
form_data_dict = {}
form_data_list = json.loads(form_data)
for field in form_data_list:
    form_data_dict[field["name"]] = field["value"]
return form_data_dict
```

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the form data using`serializeArray` function in jQuery, then convert it into dictionary and send as post data.

The `serializeArray` function output would be something like,

```
{ 
    'name': 'the_name',
    'value': 'the_value'
}
```

Then, you would have to convert it to the dictionary or json format. Write a global function for that,

```
function objectifyForm(formArray) {
    var returnArray = {};
    for (var i=0;i<formArray.length;i++) {
        if (formArray[i].value) {
            returnArray[formArray[i].name] = formArray[i].value;
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Call it whenever you have to grab the form data,

```
var formData = $('#my_form').serializeArray();
formData = objectifyForm(formData);
$.ajax({ 
        url : window.location.href, // the endpoint,commonly same url 
        type : "POST", // http method
        data : formData, 
        success: blaah,
        error: bleeh,
    });
```

It would be much less effort than having to decode the dictionary every time from the server side.