# Pass Django Variable Via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, python-3.x

I'm new to Javascript, and trying to figure out how to get the value of a variable in my HTML form.  I have the following code kind of working, I put an alert in to test my logic and the else statement is working, but I can't seem to figure out how to get Javascript to submit my form if the value is set to on.  I know my value is being interpretted correctly as I tested it with an alert as well.  It just doesn't seem to want to submit the form.  I have looked through SO and it seems that the Javascript submit syntax might have changed?  Here is my Javascript function:

```
document.getElementById('ifon').onclick = function(){
  var getval = Checkbox(this.form);
  if (getval == 'on') {
    document.getElementById("data").submit();
}  else {
    alert(getval);
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML for the form in question:

```
<form id="data" name="form_name" action="{% url 'foo:bar' record.id %}">
  <input type='hidden' name='status' value="Delete">
</form>
```

I'm new to Javascript so maybe I'm missing something.  This is a checkbox and Javascript seems to know what the value is based on my testing.  I just can't seem to get the form to submit.  Thanks for the help in advance.

Just to simplify matters and my understanding of Javascript, I've played around a bit, and can confirm that I've got the basics down.  Here's my form...

```
<form id="data" name="form_name" action="{% url 'foo:bar' record.id %}" method="POST">
  <input type='hidden' name='status' value="Delete">
</form>

<script>
function submitform()
 {
    document.form_name.submit();
 }
 </script>
```

This code doesn't appear to work.  No error messages either.

The basic Javascript principles are working, as when I change the script to something simple like...

```
<script>
function submitform()
 {
   alert("hi!");
 }
 </script>
```

I in fact see a pop up window that says hi!  This is all predicated on a button that has the onclick outlined below.  This all works fine.

```
  <button type="button" onclick="submitform()" class="button9"><h3 class="txtalgn1">Link</h3></button></a>
```

The basics of Javascript in my install seem to work.  I have updated my view to include as follows:

```
class BookUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,NeverCacheMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Book
template_name = 'book/book_update.html'
form_class = book_Update        

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(BookUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.kwargs['status'] = form.cleaned_data['status']
    return super(BookUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

But the Javascript submit still doesn't appear to be working, or if it is it's not performing the Delete based on the status...

Comment: You're telling the form to submit itself, but where is it supposed to be submitting to? The form has no action parameter to set a destination.

Comment: Daniel Roseman thanks for the guidance.  I've added an action parameter to my form but it doesn't seem to help.  I'm using Django forms, does that influence the solution?

Comment: No what you've done makes no sense. The action attribute is the URL the form submits to.

Comment: Since you indicated it had no action parameter I thought that was what you meant.

Comment: What Roseman means Steve, is that the form action does not have a URL specified to submit. In django words it should point to a URL that call a view or something. Please give us more scope in order to help you.

Comment: jsanchezs Thanks for the clarification.  Yes I've tried to include a URL in the action field but that doesn't seem to help either.  Essentially I'm trying to determine if a checkbox is checked, and if so, submit a form.  If the value is on or true, submit the form I have shown with the associated value of Delete.  I could be going about this incorrectly I'm new to Javascript and coding. I want the user to be able to click a button with HREF and ONCLICK if the checkbox is checked, submit a form with the value of Delete.

Comment: Awright, so you think your problem is in your javascript code because you already put an URL in action and doesn't work either ?

Comment: Yes I've updated the HTML with an action URL parameter and it still doesn't submit the form.

Comment: @SteveSmith check my answer and tell me how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do what you need in javascript, basically you add a custom class to the check control in the template (i asumme you're using a checkbox control for what i see in your code), then capture it, ask if is checked and then do the submit to the url you already stablished:

```
$('.mycheck').click(function(){
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
          var frm = document.getElementById("data");
          frm.submit();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django, you will need the view (and url ) correctly coded on the django side. Note that [by default csrf protection is on](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/) and you'll need either to add an csrf_exempt decorator in the django views or retrieve the csrf token from your page using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481546/how-to-send-json-serialize-data-from-a-form-to-ajax-using-django)

your view should look like this one if you're using forms:

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = yourimportedform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            yourvariable = form.cleaned_data['yourdataname']
```

EDIT: If you are running a dev server you should be able to see the logs of the http calls in real time in the terminal you've launched it in. This should help you A LOT at finding where is your mistake.

Comment: I think this may be the issue.  I'm not addressing this hence, the reason why it would appear my Javascript code is not working.  I'll investigate further.  Thanks for the input.